# Query large data from MySQL and save to CSV

Tags: mysql, pagination

Am trying to query large data from MySQL and save it to CSV. My query:

```
"SELECT id, sparks, experience FROM table_name order by id limit 1000;"
```

I need help in using "pagination" or something else, to optimize my query, as I have limits.

I tried looking at other resources like limit and offset. Am not getting all the data by using these methods. I may have to hardcode the numbers while using these methods.

If I have 100,000 records. This will give me only 1000 records. How do I change this code to get all 100,000 records?

Is there any other way where it queries smaller chunks and appends it to a big file?

Any little help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does *"they didn't work"* mean exactly? Error message? If so, edit your question and add the entire text of the error message. Results other than you expect? If so, what did you expect, and what did you get - again, edit your question and show us.

Comment: Limit and offset are give me some output, but not all the data. If I limit to 100, am getting only 100 records. With this method, I have to hardcode. Is there any other way where it queries smaller chunks and appends it to a big file?

Comment: If you want everything in a file, why not just use mysqldump?

Comment: Depends on what you want for output in the file. If it's SQL or CSV, there are commands in MySQL that will directly output those files, and they are way faster than using queries and writing the files yourself.

Comment: Am trying to query from mysql and write to CSV

Comment: con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT id, sparks, experience FROM user order by id limit 1000 ;"

cursor.execute(query)

with open('output.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(['id','sparks','experience'])
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
 writer.writerow(row)

Comment: Problem here is I cannot query the entire table at once.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
LIMIT offset, count;
```

[check this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/)

Comment: Before posting an answer, you might want to read the OP's post more carefully.

Comment: If I have 100,000 records...select * from table_name limit 0,1000; This will give me only 1000 records... how do i change this code to get all 100,000 records? Thanks !!